# How can I use a one-to-many relationship with coreData with Swift 2?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, one-to-many

I am fairly new to working with coreData and have cracked how to save and fetch items from a single entity, but I cannot seem to figure out how to save and fetch items from another entity that has a "one-to-many relationship" with the first one. I have spent ages (without success) trying to implement similar questions, but a clearer explanation would be very helpful.

I have one entity, called Group, with 3 attributes. My second entity is called Customer.

There can be many customers in a group. I have sent up the Group entity to display in a tableview and it all works. I have written the code, so that when someone taps a row on the tableview, it takes them to a new tableview in order to display the customers belonging to that Group.

How my entities are set up:

```
extension Group {
    @NSManaged var image: NSData?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var notes: String?
    @NSManaged var roundGroupRel: NSSet?
}
extension Customer {   
    @NSManaged var custName: String?
    @NSManaged var custJob: String?
    @NSManaged var custGroupRel: RoundName?
}
```

My prepareForSegue code where I try and send the information I need to the new tableViewController so I can access the customer information for that particular Group:

```
     if segue.identifier == "custList" {
            let indexPath = self.myIndexPath //the indexPath generated when the user tapped on a row
            let itemController : CustomersTVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CustomersTVC
            let nRound : Group = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Group
            itemController.aRound = nRound
            itemController.myGroupIndexPath = indexPath    
        }
```

Now the fetch request for the Group I can do:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class customerTVC: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

    var myGroupIndexPath : NSIndexPath!
    var aRound : RoundName? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        frc = getFetchedResultsController()
        frc.delegate = self
        do {
            try frc.performFetch()    
        } catch {
            print("Error: Failed to perform initial Fetch for Groups")
            return
        }

        let myGroup : Group = frc.objectAtIndexPath(myRoundIndexPath!) as! Group

        navigationItem.title = Group.name! +  " Customers:"
    }

    func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
        frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: roundFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return frc
    }
    func roundFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Group")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return fetchRequest
    }
```

This is where I need help. How do I access the customers for this particular group and not for all entries in the entity Customer?

How do I then save or add another entry to these customers?

I think I have to use the Predicate function, but I cannot figure out exactly what it is or how it works.

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you showed us your data model, but I assume the following set represents a relationship between group and customers that's holding all of the customers associated with a particular group. You don't need to do another fetch from the core data database. Just display the customers in this set.

```
@NSManaged var roundGroupRel: NSSet?
```

Comment: This what I want to learn how to do and also how do I save something into this NSSet? @beyowulf

Comment: How were your managed object classes created? Did you click on the editor menu->Create NSManagedObject Subclass? If so, Xcode creates some functions for adding objects to your roundGroupRel set.

Comment: That is how they were created. Could you give me an example of how to display what is contained in an NSSet and how to add/edit something in the set? @beyowulf